# Google App Engine GAE MemcacheService Singleton injection with Spring

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

Using com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService for caching in App Engine, I'm creating the memcacheservice instance using a factory, and injecting it into my classes with spring as a singleton.

I'm asking if this is correct and optimal and if anyone has input on the positive or negative effect of using the lazy-init option or synchronized(). I'd like to have the answer to this question result in the best possible way to use memcacheservice in this manner.

Thanks!

Factory:

```
public class CacheFactory {

    private static MemcacheService INSTANCE;

    private CacheFactory() {
    }

    public static MemcacheService getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(CacheFactory.class){
            INSTANCE =  MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;

    }



}
```

Spring Bean:

```
 <bean id="cacheFactory" class="com.nimbits.server.transactions.memcache.CacheFactory"
          factory-method="getInstance" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" >
    </bean>
```

sample usage:

```
   <bean id="someService" class="SomeServiceImpl">
        <property name="cacheFactory" ref="cacheFactory" />
   </bean>
```

Comment: I wanted to add as a comment that this code works perfectly and performs very well. I want to ensure it's optimized to handle extremely high load on app engine's environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work but it is problematic:

1. You should clearly understand that it is not a complete singleton because every instance will have its own instance of your factory.
2. It will affect dynamic instances start time. There is a known problem that every spring bean will add some time to instance start time. SO if your HTTP request will cause instance to start there will be a delay between request start and actual response process. A lot of people faced this problem during last several; months. Instance start can be even more than 60 second and you will got hard deadline Exception. So there is a recommendation not to use Spring at all to speed up start time. Check http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7706 for details.

Comment: thanks - i was hoping the answer would be the right way to use spring in the case, but "don't use spring for this" is ok with me.